# Coreplot Library - Extract entire graph image

Tags: iphone, graph, core-plot

i am creating image for graph using this code

```
UIImage *newImage=[graph imageOfLayer]
NSData *newPNG= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0); 
NSString *filePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/graph.jpg",     [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];           
if([newPNG writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES])
NSLog(@"Created new file successfully");
```

But i get only visible area(320*460) in image, How can i get whole graph image with axis.
Please provide some code snippet, how can i do it with coreplot.

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 4):

Make a new graph the size of the desired output image. It doesn't have to be added to a hosting view—that's only needed for displaying it on screen.

```
CPTXYGraph *graph = [(CPTXYGraph *)[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:desiredFrame];
// set up the graph as usual
UIImage *newImage=[graph imageOfLayer];
// process output image
```

Comment: I dont want only Visible Area Graph..i want Invisible Graph too.. Which is on scroll...i.e. i got 320 X 460 graph of which i see on  screen but i want entire graph which i see with the scroll...not just increase the frame.. but entire graph.........Example i want Xaxis 10  to 200 ..and i see on screen only 10 to 100...another 101 to 200 is in scroll..so how to get the whole image of 10 to 200 ..

Comment: When you set up the large offscreen graph, set the plot ranges to show all of the data you want to see.

Comment: OK NEED ONE MORE HELP... I ADD ONE LABLE IN Xaxis..using this code..NSMutableArray *customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[xAxisLabels count]];
    for (NSNumber *tickLocation in customTickLocations) {
              
        CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: [xAxisLabels objectAtIndex:labelLocation++] textStyle:XtextStyle];
        newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
        newLabel.offset = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength;
        newLabel.rotation = M_PI/4;
        [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
        [newLabel release];
    }

Comment: how can i add 2 lable on X axis..Bcoz i want to show the Date and Time on the X axis....Thanks for your help..

Comment: You can put the date and time on separate lines by inserting a newline character ('\n') between them. Use the `textAlignment` property of the text style to control the alignment (left, center, right).

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem was to create a method to extract the image.

In that method I momentarily make the hosting view, scroll view, graph bounds, and plot area frame bounds momentarily bigger. I then convert the graph to a an image.

I then remove the hosting view from its container to remove it from screen. I then call the doPlot method to reinitialise the plot and its data via the DoPlot method. My code is below.

There might be a visual jitter whilst this is carried out.  However, you could always disguise this by using a alert either to enter an email for export, or just a simple alert saying image exported.

```
//=============================================================================
/**
 Gets the image of the chart to export via email.
 */
//=============================================================================
-(UIImage *) getImage
{

    //Temprorarilty make plot bigger.
    // CGRect rect =  self.hostingView.bounds;
    CGRect rect =  self.scroller.bounds;
    rect.size.height = rect.size.height -100;

    rect.origin.x = 0;
    rect.size.width = rect.size.width + [fields count] * 100.0;
    [self.hostingView setBounds:rect];
    [scroller setContentSize:  hostingView.frame.size];
    graph.plotAreaFrame.bounds = rect;
    graph.bounds = rect;


    UIImage * image =[graph imageOfLayer];//get image of plot.


    //Redraw the plot back at its normal size;
    [self.hostingView removeFromSuperview];
    self.hostingView = nil;
    [self doPlot];

     return image;
}//============================================================================
```